# Is there a way to get the filepaths of a given route's middleware in Express? Or create CFG that does?

Tags: node.js, express, dependencies, abstract-syntax-tree, control-flow-graph

I am trying to create a function that would determine the dependents and dependencies of a given route's middleware in Express. The goal is to figure out how separated my routes are so that I can begin to think about the best place to begin a migration to a more microservice-based architecture.

Right now, I've figured out that I can access a list of middleware functions through Express' `app._router.router._stack` object, from which I can dig into bound and routed dispatchers for a stack of middleware. Below is the output of a function I have written to that utilizes a bunch of classes to traverse the `app` object to get a list of middleware functions.

The problem is that for anonymous functions (eg. those defined as methods on a controller), I cannot figure out a way to find the files these functions actually live in. That prevents me from easily accessing their dependencies and dependents, which I need for figuring out the function's scope and its relation to others.

**expressMap.js output:**

```
MIDDLEWARE: 

Layer {
  handle: [Function: router] {
    params: {},
    _params: [],
    caseSensitive: undefined,
    mergeParams: undefined,
    strict: undefined,
    stack: [ [Layer], [Layer] ]
  },
  name: 'router',
  params: undefined,
  path: undefined,
  keys: [],
  regexp: /^\/api\/?(?=\/|$)/i { fast_star: false, fast_slash: false },
  route: undefined
}


MIDDLEWARE HANDLERS STACK: 

/
/more-characters


FUNCTION DEFINTIONS IN ROUTE /: 

(req, res, next) => {
  console.log("inside getCharacters filecontroller")
  fsCallback.readFile(path.resolve(__dirname, '../data/characters.json'),
    'UTF-8', 
    (err, chars) => {
      if (err) return next(createErr({
          method: 'getCharacters',
          type: 'reading file',
          err,
        }));
      const parsedData = JSON.parse(chars);
      res.locals.characters = parsedData.results;
      return next();
    });
} 

(req, res, next) => {
    res.status(200).set('Content-Type', 'text/plain').json({characters : res.locals.characters})
} 

//// Note: skipping /more-characters route for space ////
```

*I think I am basically asking for a way of creating some sort of control flow graph for Express* (though ideally, one that is more agnostic would be great) that can link the routes I use to the functions they rely on in their specific context.

I initially approached this problem by making the expressMap.js function whose output is shown above, and while I could reliably list out all my middleware functions as objects and grab their definitions, I could not figure out how to get their filepaths.

I have been looking into creating some pseudo-CFG with a convoluted traversal of the Abstract Syntax Trees of my entire directory, but I can't frame the task well enough (or like, efficiently/elegantly enough) in my mind to get started. One of the main sticking points for me here is tracking calls between files (eg. going from `app.use` in server.js, to some get method in `/apiRouter.js`, to some randomController.middleware in `randomController.js`.

The hacky solution I feel would be "search for an exact match of the text of the function definition in the directory, and then return the file it is found in," but I feel there has has to be a better way.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: It might be better to use something that examines the source and builds you a dependency graph / call tree.

Comment: Thanks for the response!! I was trying to figure out something that did that but I didn't find a good batteries-included solution for call trees. Do you have any ideas? It's been difficult to search for. 

A dependency graph would be useful, but would need a good amount of functionality built on top of it, as afaik most of the ones Ive seen are meant for mapping file-to-file dependencies and not anything more granular.